# Loading images is very slow in java

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to load a few images using java but it seems to be extremely slow, it's around 13 images I'm trying to get each of 9KB size.

Is it my code or is it java that's causing the problem. I can load all the images alot faster using the browser.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ImageSample {
  static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display image");

    //Image url here
    String url="";

    JPanel panel = new testImage();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

  }
}

class testImage extends JPanel {

  static Image image;

  public  void testImage(String url)
  {
      image = Resources.getImage(url);
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 40, 40, null);
  }
}

class Resources
{
  private static Resources myResource = new Resources();

  // NOTE: there is no error checking here so if parameter is mistyped
  // somewhere else in code, then this will probably throw a nullpointerexception
  public static Image getImage(String name)
  {
    // TODO: Find out which way is better or preferred
    URL url=null;
    try {
        url = new URL(name);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

  }
}
```

Thanks,
Sreejith

Comment: Can you load some sample code also?

Comment: Can you please provide more information (e.g. critical section of code)?

Comment: By definition it's *the code* that's causing the problem by not being efficient.  The only real question is whether Java allows one to write efficient code.  In any case, you should explain what classes and approaches you're using because without that this question is unanswerable.

Comment: It is definitely your code.  I can see the problem from here :-)

Comment: @adarshr,@MAK,@Andrzej Doyle added the code.

@Stephen, You must be a magicial :-) can you check the code I added.

Comment: One more thing when I said slow I meant it's taking about 20-30 secs. to get the images but I can get it in less than 7 sec. normally

Comment: Is 'public void testImage(String url)' intended to be a constructor? 'cause it isn't one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example with your image. It is not slow.

```
public class ImageLoad extends JFrame {

   public ImageLoad() {
      setSize(800, 800);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("singer.jpg");
      JLabel label = new JLabel();
      label.setIcon(icon);
      panel.add(label);
      add(panel);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ImageLoad().setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks

I think I should have to use threads for loading all the images the same time instead of loading it one by one

Answer (score 3):

Your program isn't actually doing what you think it's doing because you have made some fundamental mistakes with your class and method names:

```
class testImage extends JPanel {

  static Image image;

  public  void testImage(String url)
  {
      image = Resources.getImage(url);
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 40, 40, null);
  }
}
```

The standard is that class names should always begin with an upper-case letter, and method names should begin with a lower-case letter to avoid confusion. Because you have confused the two, you didn't notice that the `testImage(url)` you declare in this class is a **void** method, **not** a constructor, even though the name is the same.  Therefore, when you call `JPanel panel = new testImage();` you are not calling that method - you're just calling the default empty constructor that every class is given if no constructors are declared in the code.  Note also that you haven't used the variable `url` and that your field `image` should not be static.

To be honest, you're going about the whole thing the wrong way and should start again from scratch. Costis' solution looks good. You should definitely give `ImageIcon`s a try because they remove the hard work of having to manually get the resource URL and render it.

Comment: He's saying the image loading is slow. I wonder how he's able to load the images by calling the empty constructor.

Comment: Either the code he's posted isn't the same as the code he's running, or the image never loads - that's technically very, very slow. ;)

Comment: I used the same code except with a slight mod. I used the image url directly instead of passing it as a parameter so there was no need for the constructor at that time.

Modified the code for setting dynamic image but it's buggy now

Thanks for the advice, I'm going to go with ImageIcon.